conference_auto_record sometimes not working when use api_on_answer uuid_transfer to conference
Freeswitch, conference_auto_record sometimes won't work when I transfer a connected call to conference:
set conference_auto_record=fsRecordAudioPath

bridge {api_on_answer='sched_api +1 none uuid_transfer ${uuid} -both 'conference:confname@profile' inline'}sofia/gateway/callin/abcxyz

In fs_cli, calls that cannot be recorded do not show the start record log, even though the set conference_auto_record command has been run. Hope to get help.

Since the issue with conference_auto_record is happening intermittently, it’s likely due to timing, resource conflicts, or certain call scenarios. To troubleshoot, try adding a small delay (1-2 seconds) in the sched_api command to ensure the conference is fully set up before recording starts. Compare channel variables for successful and failed calls using uuid_dump to spot inconsistencies, especially with the conference_auto_record variable. Turn on detailed logging to catch any errors or unusual behavior during the process. Also, check your system resources (CPU, memory, disk) to rule out performance issues, and test under higher call volumes to see if the problem only happens under load. Finally, make sure the variable is being passed reliably, using export if needed, and enable conference event logging to confirm when recordings are being triggered. These steps should help you pinpoint the cause.

Thank you, I have tried changing to another server with more free memory and watching to see if it still happens

Seems like this is an AI-generated answer, and all use of generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT1 and other LLMs) is banned when posting content on Stack Overflow.
This includes "asking" the question to an AI generator then copy-pasting its output as well as using an AI generator to "reword" your answers.

I also switched from SET to EXPORT and it seems to work fine
